# Firefox bug - globalCompositeOperation not working with drawImage for an SVG element

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, svg, globalcompositeoperation

I'm trying to create an 'eraser' effect in Canvas, but using an SVG image as a custom shape for the eraser.

So I can draw my SVG image to canvas, and use globalCompositeOperation='destination-out' to create a masking effect.

It works great in IE, Safari, and Chrome. But it utterly fails in Firefox.

```js
  function init() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

   var img = document.createElement('IMG');

   img.onload = function () {
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
       ctx.closePath();    
       ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';    
   }

   img.src = "http://www.evanburke.com/FROST.png";
   var svg = new Image;
   svg.src = "http://www.evanburke.com/luf.svg";
   
   function drawPoint(pointX,pointY){
       ctx.drawImage(svg,pointX,pointY);  
   }   
   canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    drawPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
   },false);   
  }
```

```html
 <body onload="javascript:init();">
 <div>     
     <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: raise  bug in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org) then

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed a bug, and as advised by @RobertLongson, you should raise a bug in [Mozilla's Buzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).
But first, you should clean up your code :  `ctx.beginPath()` is useless. and `ctx.closePath()` doesn't do what yo think it does.

If you want a workaround for this issue, you could first draw the svg image onto a canvas, then use this canvas as the eraser :

```js
(function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var svgCan;
  var img = document.createElement('IMG');

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  }

  img.src = "http://www.evanburke.com/FROST.png";
  var svg = new Image();
  svg.src = "http://www.evanburke.com/luf.svg";
  svg.onload = function() {
    // create a canvas
    svgCan = canvas.cloneNode();
    svgCan.width = this.width;
    svgCan.height = this.height;
    // draw the svg on this new canvas
    svgCan.getContext('2d').drawImage(svg, 0, 0);
  }

  function drawPoint(pointX, pointY) {
    // this is now a pixel image that will work with gCO
    ctx.drawImage(svgCan, pointX, pointY);
  }
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    drawPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }, false);
})()
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```